# Нужно заменить библиотечный класс своим

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

в либе Chatto шаг с перекрытием клавиатурой поля ввода. Библиотека не обновлялась а баг именной в ней вот хочу заменить библиотечный KeyboardTracker на свой ( с исправлением бага ) подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать ?